# Why image not displaying on React Typescript and Styled Component

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I'm trying to display an image in a react project, which is created with typescript template.

The code runs and the page shows only image icon, but not the image itself. What am I doing wrong?

I used: create-react app --template typescript. I can't access it if I place it in the public directory. So the folder is placed in the src directory.

this is how it looks like the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const logo = require('../../src/images/logo.png');

const StyledTable = styled.div``;

export const MyPage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <StyledTable>
      <img alt="Profile Image" style={{ width: 100 }} src={String(logo)} />
    </StyledTable>
  );
};

export default MyPage;
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Create-React-App? If so, there is [an easier way to import images](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)

Copied from the doc

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // Just import it

console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Great. Thank you.  It works now, although, I have applied the same method importing from the src dirctory.

Comment: Not working for me with create-react-library